# Setting custom font in android application

Tags: android, custom-font

Is it possible to set a customised font for an entire android application in one shot. I mean I do not want to use `setTypeFace` for every textview in every activity. And not only textviews but every possible text.

Comment: make your customized textview with custom font set, and use that textview instead of default textview

Answer (score 9):

Just make your own TextView:

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {

// make every constructor call init();

  private void init() {
   setTypeFace(...);
  }

}
```

In xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.yourcompany.yourproject.views.CustomFontTextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:text="Test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not only textviews but everything, say buttons, web layout etc. in short all the text in the app

Comment: any solution  for above comment ? i have made the necessary change in the question also.

Comment: There is no way to change it everywhere from the application.

Comment: following your answer, probably, one has to extend `view` class and then extend every view type used in the app